# How to remove all the IPC-Message queue ?

Tags: c, linux, unix, ipc

Consider I have created a 100 messages queues using a msgget() function.

```
 ------ Message Queues --------
 key        msqid      owner      perms      used-bytes   messages    
0x00000000 262144     bhuvaneshw 666        40           2           
0x00000000 294913     bhuvaneshw 666        40           2           
0x00000000 327682     bhuvaneshw 666        40           2           
0x00000000 360451     bhuvaneshw 666        40           2           
0x00000000 393220     bhuvaneshw 666        40           2           
0x00000000 425989     bhuvaneshw 666        55           3        
....
.....
....
```

Using a `ipcrm` command we can remove the single queue at a time.

```
ipcrm -q queue_id
```

or else using a `msgctl()` we can remove that. But I want to remove all the message queues in single instant . Is there is any way to do this in linux?

Comment: can you try like `ipcs -a | grep 0x | awk '{printf( "-Q %s ", $1 )}' | xargs ipcrm`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one,

```
ipcrm -q 262144 -q ... -q ...
```

You can give like this. Option is must.

Answer (score 5):

ipcrm can do just that:

```
ipcrm --all=msg
```

Instead of msg you can use sem and shm for semaphores and shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option `-Q` in `ipcrm`that deletes all the messages in the queue. 
For instance, `ipcrm -Q 0x00000000` deletes all the messages for the key `0x00000000`

Comment: @Dimitri- ok But I need to remove all the queues in my system.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I got you the answer

you can delete message queue's using KEY number running in loop from starting to max range(use system() function), 
but message Queue with KEY=0, cannot be removed in that way 
->" `ipcrm -Q 0` " not possible, 
so better way is to get mesQid for each key, then use msgctl(msgQid,IPC_RMID,0);
in this way you can remove with key=0 also;

so problem sums up to get msgqid by avoiding msgget()
(read MSG_INFO and MSG_STAT from $man 2 msgctl)

so now,
loop over the kernel's index system for active message queues,
then get the msgqid using sequential index and looping
i.e `msqid = msgctl(ind, MSG_STAT, &ds)`, so thats  it.

for cleaner understanding read through  MSG_INFO and MSG_STAT from 
`$man 2 msgctl`.

or a cleaner code i tried here and working
https://github.com/chetanDN/linux-system-programming/blob/master/IPC/messageQ/2.deleteMsgQ/deleteAllCurrentMsgQs.c